# how to custom useFetch in nuxt3?

Tags: fetch, refresh-token, nuxt3, usefetch

I've tried many ways to custom useFetch but always got something wrong
here is my goal:
If token expires(request got 401),auto refresh token and store other new requests into array and wait for refresh executing.
If refresh success then execute request in list.
also retry origin fail request.

but now, I only got request fail immediatlly.
although refresh could execute correctly, but neither origin request nor requests in list did not execut correctly

```
import type { FetchResponse, SearchParameters } from 'ofetch'
import type { UseFetchOptions } from '#app'
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash'
import { useUserStore } from '../stores/userStore'
import { refreshToken } from '../apis/auth'
import { defu } from 'defu'

let isRefreshing = false
const requestQueue: Array<{ resolve: Function, reject: Function }> = []
export interface ResOptions<T> {
    data?: T
    code?: number
    message?: string
}
type UrlType = string | Request | Ref<string | Request> | (() => string | Request)
export type HttpOption<T> = UseFetchOptions<ResOptions<T>>


export const myFetch = async <T>(url: UrlType, httpOptions: HttpOption<T> = {}) => {
    const userStore = useUserStore()
    const config = useRuntimeConfig()
    const defaults: HttpOption<T> = {
        baseURL: `${config.public.apiBase}/api`,
        async onRequest({ request, options }) {
            options.headers = options.headers || {}

            if (userStore.isLogin) {
                (options.headers as { [key: string]: string }).authorization = `Bearer ${userStore.token}`
            }
        },
        async onResponse({ request, response, options }) {
            if (response._data.code !== 200) {
                console.log(response._data.message);
            }
            // return response._data
        },
        async onResponseError({ request, response }) {
            if (response._data.code === 401 && response.headers.get('Token-Expired') === 'true') {
                if (!isRefreshing) {
                    const refreshPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        requestQueue.push({ resolve, reject })
                    })
                    isRefreshing = true
                    const refreshSuccess = await refreshToken()
                    isRefreshing = false
                    if (refreshSuccess) {
                        for (const { resolve, reject } of requestQueue) {
                            try {
                                const newResponse = await useFetch(url, httpOptions)
                                resolve(newResponse)
                            } catch (error) {
                                reject(error)
                            }
                        }
                        requestQueue.length = 0

                    } else {
                        for (const { reject } of requestQueue) {
                            reject('Refresh Fail')
                        }
                        requestQueue.length = 0
                    }
                    debugger
                    const response = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                        try {
                            const initialResponse = await myFetch(url, httpOptions)
                            resolve(initialResponse)
                        } catch (error) {
                            reject(error)
                        }
                    })
                    return response
                } else {
                    const promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                        requestQueue.push({ resolve, reject })
                    })
                    return promise
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log(response._data.message);
                return response._data;
            }
        },
    }
    const params = defu(httpOptions, defaults)
    return await useFetch(url, params)
}


export const useCustomFetch = {
    get: async <T>(url: UrlType, params?: any, option?: HttpOption<T>) => {
        return await myFetch<T>(url, { method: 'get', params, ...option })
    },

    post: async <T>(url: UrlType, body?: any, option?: HttpOption<T>) => {
        return await myFetch<T>(url, { method: 'post', body, ...option })
    },

    put: async <T>(url: UrlType, body?: any, option?: HttpOption<T>) => {
        return await myFetch<T>(url, { method: 'put', body, ...option })
    },

    delete: async <T>(url: UrlType, body?: any, option?: HttpOption<T>) => {
        return await myFetch<T>(url, { method: 'delete', body, ...option })
    },
}
```